# Convert rows to columns and calculate sum

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have this

[image]

And I want this

[image]

But I am getting this instead

[image]

My query is

```
SELECT   SID, 
         NAME, 
         SUBJECT, ( 
         CASE 
                  WHEN EXAMTYPE IN ('ASSIGNMENTS', 
                                    'PRACTICAL') THEN SUM(MARKS) 
                  ELSE 0 
         END) AS "ASSIGNMENTS + PRACTICAL", ( 
         CASE 
                  WHEN EXAMTYPE = 'WRITTEN' THEN SUM(MARKS) 
                  ELSE 0 
         END) AS "WRITTEN"
FROM     MARKSHEET 
WHERE    EXAMTYPE IN ('ASSIGNMENTS', 
                      'PRACTICAL', 
                      'WRITTEN') 
GROUP BY SID, 
         NAME, 
         SUBJECT, 
         EXAMTYPE
```

I am using IBM DB2.
I will be eternally grateful for any/all help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your case expression in sum() - like `sum(case when...)`
Also, remove `examType` field from the `group by clause`

```
SELECT   SID, 
         NAME, 
         SUBJECT, sum( 
         CASE 
                  WHEN EXAMTYPE IN ('ASSIGNMENTS', 
                                    'PRACTICAL') THEN MARKS 
                  ELSE 0 
         END) AS "ASSIGNMENTS + PRACTICAL", ( 
         sum(CASE 
                  WHEN EXAMTYPE = 'WRITTEN' THEN MARKS
                  ELSE 0 
         END) AS "WRITTEN"
FROM     MARKSHEET 
WHERE    EXAMTYPE IN ('ASSIGNMENTS', 'PRACTICAL', 'WRITTEN') 
GROUP BY SID, NAME, SUBJECT
```